# How can I obtain a yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss string from a Date object in pure old JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am not so into JavaScript. I have the following problem trying to format a `Date`. I can use only plain old JavaScript (no third party library because this script is not performed into the browser but into a Java application using Rhino).

I created my `Date` object in this way:

```
d = new Date('2017','11','09','06','00','00');
```

(into the Rhino environment the `Date()` constructor works only in this way).

That creates a `Date` object like this:

> Sat Dec 09 2017 06:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)

Starting from this `Date` object I want to obtain a String formatted in this way:

> yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss

I know that doing:

```
d.toISOString()
```

I obtain

> 2017-12-09T05:00:00.000Z

but it contains the **T** and **Z** delimiters.

What is a smart way to do it?

Comment: Have you looked over the basic Date API? There are methods for extracting each part of the date, and you can use those to create a string that looks like whatever you want.

Comment: String-replace `T` to a space and `Z` to an empty string? The native API does not really have proper formatting methods.

Comment: @zerkms Was about to type that, but with `.000Z` to empty.

Comment: Do you strictly need a JavaScript Date object? Could you use Java Date instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reformat the ISO string by replace the unnecessary parts with a space, then [String#trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) the spaces from the end.

Thanks to @zerkms for the [regex expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211251/how-can-i-obtain-a-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-string-from-a-date-object-in-pure-old-jav/47211309#comment81372039_47211309).

```js
var d = new Date('2017','11','09','06','00','00');

var str = d.toISOString().replace(/T|Z|\.\d{3}/g, ' ').trim();

console.log(str);
```